# Leave out discriminator part of Doctrine' generated SQL

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm, indexing, dql

Assume the following `AbstractPage` model:

```
/*
 *     @ORM\Entity
 *     @ORM\Table(name="page")
 *     @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 *     @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 *     @ORM\DiscriminatorMap
 *     ({
 *         "page" = "Page",
 *         "link" = "Link"
 *     })
 */
```

And the following DQL query:

```
SELECT p FROM \Page\Model\AbstractPage
```

The generated SQL will be:

```
SELECT ... FROM page p0_ WHERE p0_.type IN ('page', 'link')
```

Now to the question: how can I remove the `WHERE` clause from this query. On more complex queries this part of the `WHERE` clause makes it not possible to use some indexes that are defined. This can be resolved by adding `type` to the indexes, but this makes my indexes larger and I feel this is not necessary.

The `AbstractPage` is the root in the inheritance tree. Thus we are interested in ALL records in the table. Omiting the `WHERE` part does precisely that.

So the question is: how can I make Doctrine remove this `WHERE` part where it is not necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth: using Doctrine 2.2, I don't have this WHERE part, but I have a difference: I'm not using SINGLE_TABLE, JOINED instead. I don't know if it's the version or this setting that alters the WHERE.

Comment: Pity: difference is in version!

Comment: Which version of doctrine do you use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution I can think out. The idea is to extend some doctrine classes to add functionality required.
Keep models as they are now.

Create new class extending SqlWalker (update namespaces of course)

```
<?php

namespace Sad;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

class CustomSqlWalker extends SqlWalker
{

  const IGNORE_DISCRIMINATION = 'ignoreDiscrimination';

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function walkWhereClause($whereClause)
  {
    // Get list of aliases in which discrimination should be ignored
    $ignoreDescription = $this->getQuery()->getHint(self::IGNORE_DISCRIMINATION);
    if ($ignoreDescription !== false) {
      // For each aliases...
      foreach ($this->getQueryComponents() as $k => $component) {
        // ...check if alias is in ignore list
        if (in_array($k, $ignoreDescription)) {
          /** @var $metaObj ClassMetadata */
          $metaObj = $component['metadata'];
          // Update inheritance type to disable discrimination where
          if ($metaObj->isInheritanceTypeSingleTable()) {
            $metaObj->setInheritanceType(ClassMetadata::INHERITANCE_TYPE_NONE);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return parent::walkWhereClause($whereClause);
  }
}
```

Then making query you do the following:

```
echo $entityManager->createQuery("SELECT p FROM \Sad\Schema\AbstractPage as p")->getSQL();
// Output: ELECT p0_.id AS id_0, p0_.name AS name_1, p0_.type AS type_2 FROM page p0_ WHERE p0_.type IN ('page', 'link')

$query = $entityManager->createQuery("SELECT p FROM \Sad\Schema\AbstractPage as p");
// Make sure query uses custom walker
$query->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER, 'Sad\CustomSqlWalker');
// Specify which aliases should ignore discrimination
$query->setHint(\Sad\CustomSqlWalker::IGNORE_DISCRIMINATION, array('p'));

echo $query->getSQL();
// Output: ELECT p0_.id AS id_0, p0_.name AS name_1, p0_.type AS type_2 FROM page p0_
```

Comment: You're welcome. It is quite difficult to extend Query and SqlWalker. Many methods are marked as private and Query class is final. So that's the only thing can be done. The code could be improved of course by adding input parameters verification etc.